# MySql select records between ranges

Tags: mysql, range, between

I've defined following table as follows.

```
categories (id, start, end, price)
```

and values are

```
id start end price
 1   2    4   1000
 2   5    10  3000
 3   11   30  5000
```

If I'm having value `3` and it should select `1st` row.

The query should be like as following

```
3 >= start and 3 <= end
```

But I can't able to select the records here and I've tried as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 3 >= start and 3 <= end;
```

Please suggest me solution the work would be appreciated.

Comment: It working fine for me and give me first record. What your problem?

Comment: what your actual problem? you do not get any record?

Answer (score 1):

This statement solve your problem:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 3 between start and  end;
```

Comment: is between closer set? does it include values of 3. i.e start or end equals 3

Comment: @SharanabasuAngadi Yes it include 3 in the interval.

Comment: Above question working fine for me and give me first record. What  problem?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what actual your problem as per your suggestion it's working fine.

```
SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE 3 >= start and 3 <= end;
```

Check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/528a61/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start <= 3  and end >= 3;
```

Comment: Above question working fine for me and give me first record. What  problem?

Answer (score 0):

instead of comparing constants with start and end compare `start` and end with constants 
like as user1442034 said

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start <= 3 and end >= 3;
```

Comment: Above question working fine for me and give me first record. What  problem?